# What is the Docker Scratch Linux equivalent base image in Windows Containers?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

In linux container, Scratch is the starting point for any linux containers. It has no folder/file in it. `FROM scratch` is a no-op in the Dockerfile, and will not create an extra layer in your image (so a previously 2-layer image will be a 1-layer image instead). ([Ref](https://hub.docker.com/_/scratch))

For windows, so far there are 4 base image known ([Ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/container-base-images))

- Nano Server (`mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver`)
- Windows Server Core (`mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore`)
- Windows Server (`mcr.microsoft.com/windows/server`)
- Windows (`mcr.microsoft.com/windows`)

Nano Server is few hundreds MB, so it doesn't come close to `scratch` linux image of few bytes only.

Comment: The `scratch` image contains literally nothing (and takes some advanced Linux knowledge to use it effectively).  If you have the corresponding Windows knowledge to copy in required DLL files and similar, can you use `scratch` on Windows as well?

Comment: @DavidMaze I'm not too sure what advance knowledge is required for Windows to make `scratch` work. But I tried simply use scratch on Windows container, the error is simply "Linux containers are not supported on this system"